# Hibernate is broken: where are the logs?

Tags: hibernate

Hibernation doesn't work anymore for me. Where can I find the related logs?

Thanks

Comment: same here.. I have installed latest version of Ubuntu and i am having the same problem

Comment: Finally, I solved my issue with this [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate) by simply doing `sudo apt-get install uswsusp`. Hope it helps

Comment: Kernel-space suspension is generally favoured over user-space suspension though.

Comment: I guessed so, but I could not find any info on which were the compromises doing user-space instead of kernel-space. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relevant log files are all underneath `/var/log`:

- `pm-suspend.log`
- `syslog`

The output of `dmesg` may also contain valuable information, whether the failure occurs during suspension or wake-up.

You may also find [How to debug suspend?](/q/16239/175814) interesting.